# Issue with passing payload to another flow in munit

Tags: mule

I am reading the JSON from the .txt file in MUnit test case, setting it to payload.I expect that payload has the field and its value defined in .txt file in form of map. However I am getting null instead of value.
Appreciate your help in isolating the issue.

```
<!-- TESTCASE: -->
<munit:test name="test-update" description="Validate calls to sub flows are being done properly ">
     <munit:set payload="#[getResource('testData.txt').asStream()]" doc:name="Set Message">
    <munit:inbound-properties>
    <munit:inbound-property key="http.method" value="#['POST']" />
    <munit:inbound-property key="http.request" value="#['/api/service/v1/update']" />
    <munit:inbound-property key="http.request.path" value="#['/api/service/v1/update']" />
     </munit:inbound-properties>
</munit:set>

<byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object" /> 

<logger level="INFO" message="Payload: #[payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<!-- Logs {"Id":"123"} which is read from testData.txt --> 

<logger level="INFO" message="Id: #[payload.Id]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<!-- Logs "Id= null" instead of "Id: 123"--> 

...
</munit:test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<logger level="INFO" message="Id: #[payload.get('Id')]" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<logger level="INFO" message="Id: #[payload.Id]" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: I am getting "Execution of the expression "payload.get('Id')" failed." error. FYI: testData.txt has following data in it: {"Id":"123"}

Comment: <byte-array-to-object-transformer /> is returning string payload. You will have to use <json:json-to-object-transformer /> and then extract value using #[payload.get('Id')]